# In Arkham Horror, can "Any Phase" actions be performed multiple times immediately?

Tags: arkham-horror

The item in mind is the Enchanted Jewelry which can prevent one stamina damage any phase (and gets discarded once 3 stamina tokens have piled up on the card). Does this mean it can only be used to prevent 1 stamina loss during that phase, or can I prevent 3 damage at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that you would be unable to repeat the "Any Phase" ability on a card is if you must exhaust the card to use the ability (e.g. [Dragon's Eye](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Dragon%27s_Eye)), or if it explicitly says that you can only use the ability once per turn (e.g. [Mandy Thompson](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Mandy_Thompson)'s ability). Since the Enchanted Jewelry meets neither of these conditions, it can be used multiple times per turn, including repeatedly from the same attack. The same also applies to the [Shotgun](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Shotgun).